# vuejs treeselect - disable only top level checkbox

Tags: vue.js

Using treeselect (https://vue-treeselect.js.org) with the Delayed Loading feature to reduce loading time since using a large data file.

To shorten the length of the initial dropdown list, created a top level category which only groups data in categories (21 categories were created).

Is there a way to disable branch nodes (`disableBranchNodes` option) only at the top level but have the second level be checkable to include all children at once?

Ex:
top category **Fruit and Vegetable Products (73)** (need not to be checkable)
second level **Citrus Fruit (5)** (need to be checkable)
children (separate checkbox):

- Oranges
- Mandarins
- Grapefruit
- Lemons and Lime
- Citrus Fruits Nes

Note: Didn't find answer in the related question "vuejs treeselect - conditional checkbox".

Comment: Well why do you "shorten" the initial list but want people to still be able to expand it and browse it? What's the reason of this? Since the user clicked on the input field, he _wants_ to do something with it. It's just another step to go there. I don't think there's an option to disable an item without disabling it's children, and it shouldn't be, honestly :)

Comment: The reason is instead of having an initial list of 1222 parent products to go through, there are now only 21 items to help narrow the parent search and find easier the product.